# What are the sources of Mawdu'/Fabricated Ahadeeth?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith, authenticity

Some fabricated Ahadeeth come from an individuals self, but others come from other sources, like sayings of scholars, poets and doctors.  So, what are the sources of fabricated Ahadeeth? What are the types of fabricated Ahadeeth that are out there?

Answer (score 2):

There is a set of volumes compiled by Sh. Naasir-ud-deen Al-Albaani. But it's in Arabic.

> سلسلة الأحاديث الضعيفة والموضوعة

I don't know if there's an official translation to this title but I read the title as:

> Chain of weak and fabricated Ahaadeeth

I hope this is useful.